Changing 1-1-1900 to current date
I am using this VBA code to change the system date to current date, instead of typing 23-August-2024 manually I only type 23 inside the cell and hit enter it changes to 23-August-2024. So I am using this code to avoid January-1990. But my problem is whenever I delete the cell which I entered the date. Instead of deleting, it changes it to 31-July.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, rint As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
    Set rint = Intersect(rng, Target)

    For Each r In rint
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            r.Value = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), r.Value)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Next r
End Sub


When you delete the cell, the code is called.
When it gets to the line r.Value = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), r.Value), it looks, and gets no result for r.Value.
So, it treats r.Value as 0.
Therefore, it changes r.Value to 2024-08-00 — just as you told it to.  And the Zeroth day of this month (August) is, programmatically, the same as the last day of the previous month (July).  Thus, 2024-08-00 becomes 2024-07-31.
As such: you should probably check whether r.value is between 1 and 31 before you use it.  (Otherwise, you'll also get a completely different error if you type in an actual date: 2024-08-23 = 45527 → DateSerial(2024, 08, 45527) = 2114-04-18)
An even more advanced check would be to see if it is between 1 and the number of days in this month.  This prevents issues like "typing 30 in February" (1st or 2nd of March, depending on whether or not it's a Leap year).
Application.EnableEvents = False
If IsNumeric(r.Value) Then 'In case you typed text
    If r.Value = Application.Median(1, r.Value, Day(DateSerial(Year(Date),Month(Date)+1,0))) Then 'Valid for this month
        r.Value = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), r.Value)
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True


Thank you for your reply and explanation. Well the only thing I want from excel to do for me is when I type a number between 1-30 and hit enter I would get the current month and year thats all. It’s boring to type the whole thing every time when you have 100 cells. Now when i type a day number and hit enter it gives me automatically Jan-1990. Maybe there is a suitable code for that out there but I don’t know.
